# How to spit out a headline, photo(s) and story from news article using PHP

Tags: php, html, web, backend

Ok so I am fairly lost and frustrated, I've been reading and working on this for hours and when I feel like I make progress...I find out I really haven't.

Problem:Take a news article from some place like cnn.com and make a php web application that spits out the headline, the story, and any photos. Make sure to strip all HTML tags.
Must use classes, constructors, and CANNOT use 3rd party libraries, native PHP is ok.

So here is the article I am working on 
http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/18/us/delmarva-peninsula-squirrel-endangered-species-feat/index.html

Where I left last from frustration is this, it pulls out everything I need, but leaves the raw code showing too.

```
$url='http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/18/us/delmarva-peninsula-squirrel-endangered-species-feat/index.html';

$element = file_get_contents($url);
echo strip_tags($element , "<h1>, <img>, <p>");
```

I had this at one point as well

```
//Class Structure
class ThisIsMyClass {
    public $aHTMLContent = 'HTMLContent';
    public $aHeader = 'Header';
    public $aPictures = 'Pictures';
}

$ThisIsMyClass = new ThisIsMyClass;


//Title For Page
$element = 'Header'
$ThisIsMyClass->$element=file_get_contents("http://www.cnn.com/tech", 20);
preg_match("/<title>(.*)</title>/i", $html, $match);
$title = $match[1];
echo $element . '<br>';

//HTML Content
$element2 = 'HTMLContent'
$ThisIsMyClass->$element2=getHTML("http://www.cnn.com/tech");
echo $element2 . '<br>';

//Get all images from page
$element3 = 'Pictures';
foreach($element2->find"img" as $element3)
echo $element3->src . '<br>';

?>
```

I see a ton of "use curl" but since curl is 3rd party I cannot use it. I have seen pulling the title specific, but the actual title is in a meta tag. I followed a couple examples on here for extracting meta tags, but I get errors that apparently no other post gets.

Please help! I need to finish this tonight, I have done my due diligence on it and I just do not know where else to look.

Ok...so I've spent the last two hours trying to look at how to add a class and constructor to this where it makes sense....

Every example I can find is the stereotypical

```
class human
{
function talk{
echo "Hello"}
}
```

etc....I am having trouble seeing how this relates to what I have going on. I am basically going off of the code structure that Chris85 posted below. I do not see how the info from the code below involves classes and a constructor....can someone help with some hints, examples, or a good tutorial that involves something a little closer to what I am working with??

Comment: You realize that both `$element = 'Header'` and `$element2 = 'HTMLContent'` are missing closing semi-colons. If that is your actual code, error reporting would be throwing you parse errors. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You'll probably find it better to use a parser than regexs for HTML. PHP has native parsers built into it as well.

Comment: I've tried looking at DOMDocument, and Simple DOM Parser, and every example I see is throwing them into an output in the form of an array. Or they use it to spit out a loop of something like a comment feed so a loop is needed. I cannot find an example for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example using the DOM parser to output all `h1`, `img`, and `p` elements content.

```
$url='http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/18/us/delmarva-peninsula-squirrel-endangered-species-feat/index.html';
$string = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
output_these_elements(array('h1', 'img', 'p'), $doc);
function output_these_elements($elements, $doc) {
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        echo $element . "\n\n";
        $domelements = $doc->getElementsByTagName($element);
        foreach($domelements as $domelement) {
            if($element == 'img') {
                echo $domelement->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
            } else {
                echo $domelement->nodeValue . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
h1

Nuts to you! Squirrel gets off endangered species list
img

data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110249-01-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110527-02-animals-endangered-species-restricted-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110554-03-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110627-04-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110842-05-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110903-06-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110938-07-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111005-08-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111029-09-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111059-10-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111206-11-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111225-12-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKlI+py+0Po5yUFQA7
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111242-13-animals-endangered-species-super-169.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110249-01-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110527-02-animals-endangered-species-restricted-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110554-03-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110627-04-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110842-05-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110903-06-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118110938-07-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111005-08-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111029-09-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111059-10-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111206-11-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111225-12-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151118111242-13-animals-endangered-species-small-11.jpg
p

By Todd Leopold, CNN

Updated 3:54 PM ET, Wed November 18, 2015 
 (CNN)Forget about gathering nuts. A rare species of squirrel has gathered new life.
The Delmarva Peninsula fox squirrel, one of the animals on the original endangered species list, is now no longer at risk of extinction, says the U.S. Department of the Interior.
"The fox squirrel's return to this area, rich with farmland and forest, marks not only a major win for conservationists and landowners, but also represents the latest in a string of success stories that demonstrate the Endangered Species Act's effectiveness," Interior official Michael Bean said from Prime Hook National Wildlife Refuge in Milton, Delaware, according to a Department of the Interior statement. 
The squirrel -- native to Delaware and coastal Maryland and Virginia (DelMarVa, get it?) -- will be officially removed from the list in December.
The Delmarva Peninsula fox squirrel was one of 78 species listed under the Endangered Species Preservation Act in 1967, the first year the list appeared. It continued on the successor list of Threatened and Endangered Wildlife under the Endangered Species Act, passed in 1973.
It's one of 30 species to have been delisted, according to the Interior Department. Others include the peregrine falcon, the American alligator and the national bird of the United States, the bald eagle.
Not all species make it, despite being listed. The Santa Barbara song sparrow was noted as extinct in 1983 despite 10 years on the list. Also considered extinct are the longjaw cisco, a fish once found in the Great Lakes; the Mariana mallard, a duck native to the Mariana Islands; and the Caribbean monk seal, a once-common Gulf of Mexico seal -- Columbus recorded their existence in 1494 -- that was delisted in 2008 after an exhaustive search.
The Delmarva Peninsula fox squirrel also had a difficult climb back to its current population. Larger than your average suburban nut-hoarder, it was widely found in the rural areas of the Delmarva Peninsula, a landmass between the Chesapeake Bay and the Atlantic Ocean. 
But decades of development and overhunting, starting in the 1950s, limited the fox squirrel's habitat and threatened its existence.
However, "since listing, the squirrel's range has increased from four to 10 counties, and a population of up to 20,000 squirrels now covers 28 percent of the Delmarva Peninsula, primarily in Maryland," the Interior Department's statement observed. (No word on whether Atlanta's Inman Park Squirrel Census contributed to the counting.)
Still, just because the squirrel is no longer endangered, don't expect to head out immediately and start grabbing a few for dinner. According to a fact sheet, "Deliberate killing of any animal is permissible only during an open hunting season defined under state law in Maryland, Delaware and Virginia." Those states haven't decided on any details.
Not bad, Delmarva Peninsula fox squirrel. You're out of the woods -- that is, if you wanted to leave.
```

Comment: Thank you, that is actually very helpful, I think the output of other examples I saw was what was confusing me. This gives me a point to continue forward on to look at how to display the images, and possibly get rid of the "h1" "img" and "p" texts that is in the output